# Where to add subviews in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Is there some "best-practice" way to add subviews to a `UIScrollView`?

For Example:

I have a `UIViewController` which loads images with corresponding description from a server.
Those *images+descriptions* should be added in a horizontal scrollView.

When the data is loaded, should I create a method in my `UIView` to handle this stuff,
or is it more convenient to do this in my `UIViewController`?

Comment: Any particular reason for not to use `UITableView`?

Comment: It should be horizontal swipe-stuff instead of vertically scrolling through a tableView

Comment: Consider `UICollectionView` then.

Comment: +1 `UICollectionView`. It might require a little learning on your part, but it's an essential tool in your iOS tookit. It gives you *way* more flexibility i̶f̶ when you try to do something fancy.

Comment: I know `UICollectionView`is another option, but that's not the point here :) I was just wondering which solutions would be the more convenient one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller would be an most appropriate place to handle this, as controllers should connect your view (the scroll view) to the data (the images).

If the scroll view's layout is simple, it could be done entirely with the controller. But, if the layout is complex, you may want to consider subclassing `UIScrollView` and handling some of the layout there (similar to how `UITableView` works).

For more info on standard application architecture, read [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) on Apple's developer site.

Comment: I was thinking the same way using the `UIViewController` in the MVC-pattern as the connection between the view and the data! Thanks for the answer!:)

Answer (score 0):

By my way of looking at it, the separation of concerns would break down like this:

- the `UIViewController` is responsible for getting the images and handing them to the `UIView`
- `UIView` is responsible for displaying them.

So the `-addSubview:` is a view implementation detail, should go in the view, and be opaque to the controller.

There is plenty of opinion that both `UIViewController` and `UIView` are confused and intertwined in such a way to make them both part of the conceptual "view" (in a MVC sense), but I think it's still cleaner this way.

As you can see, opinions differ. :) Personally, I despair of MVC, and think [Model-View-ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) to be a much clearer, cleaner, and more sensible way of approaching all this.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView is same as that of UITableView except it is meant to display Images and its description.

Here is what you can do.

1. Create a UICollectionView, it is the subclass of UIScrollView. SO there is no need of UIScrollview.
2. Since you need image and description both for each item, I will recommend delete the UICollectionViewItem from UICollectionView.
3. Create a seperate custom UICollectinViewItem class, define UICollectionItem in .xib file (UIImageVIew and UILabel).
4. When you define the datasource method "– collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:" define the UICollectionVIewItem class here. Exactly we defines custom UITableVIewCell.